# How can i count video view in php without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my code check and gives me any suggestions Thanks StackOverflow team

```
<video onclick="
             <?php 
              $slectips = "SELECT * FROM unique_visitors WHERE ipaddress = '$uuser_id'";
              $checkipNumber = mysqli_query($conn,$slectips);
              $numbersofviews = mysqli_num_rows($checkipNumber);
              if($numbersofviews==0)
              {
                  $insertips = "INSERT INTO `unique_visitors`(`ipaddress`) VALUES ('$uuser_id')";
                  $Ipquery = mysqli_query($conn,$insertips);
                  if($Ipquery==true)
                  {
                      $insertview = "UPDATE `videos` SET `views`= views +1 WHERE id = '".$row['id']."'";
                     $Viewquery = mysqli_query($conn,$insertview);
                  if($Viewquery==true)
                  {
                      echo "<script>alert('Suceessfully Ips Adress And Views Inseted');</script>";
                  }
                      else
                      {
                          echo "<script>alert('ERROR UPDATING VIEW');</script>";
                      }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      echo "<script>alert('ERROR INSERTING IPS YOUR IP MATCH');</script>";
                  }
              }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Your Ip AVAILABLE IN DATABASE');</script>";
        }


            ?>                
           " id='my_video' src="<?php echo $images; ?>" controls></video>
```

please help me I don't know how can I count video view and insert into the database in PHP without refreshing page

Comment: you can make a function in javascript and onclick use it with ajax

Answer (score 0):

As i say here a example on how to use AJAX with ONCLICK

```
//page one1
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video onclick="sendcount('<?php echo $uuser_id;?>')" id='my_video' src="<?php echo $images; ?>" controls></video>

<script>
function sendcount(uuser_id)
{

     $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "page2.php",
                         data: {"uuser_id":uuser_id},
                         async: true,
                         success: function(data){ 
          var obj = JSON.parse(data);
         alert(obj.msg);

          }})



}


</script>
</body>
</html>

// page 2
<?php 

$uuser_id=$_POST['uuser_id'];
$msg='';

              $slectips = "SELECT * FROM unique_visitors WHERE ipaddress = '$uuser_id'";
              $checkipNumber = mysqli_query($conn,$slectips);
              $numbersofviews = mysqli_num_rows($checkipNumber);
              if($numbersofviews==0)
              {
                  $insertips = "INSERT INTO `unique_visitors`(`ipaddress`) VALUES ('$uuser_id')";
                  $Ipquery = mysqli_query($conn,$insertips);
                  if($Ipquery==true)
                  {
                      $insertview = "UPDATE `videos` SET `views`= views +1 WHERE id = '".$row['id']."'";
                     $Viewquery = mysqli_query($conn,$insertview);
                  if($Viewquery==true)
                  {
                      $msg="alert('Suceessfully Ips Adress And Views Inseted');";
                     // echo "<script>alert('Suceessfully Ips Adress And Views Inseted');</script>";
                  }
                      else
                      {$msg="ERROR UPDATING VIEW";
                         // echo "<script>alert('ERROR UPDATING VIEW');</script>";
                      }
                  }
                  else
                  {$msg="ERROR INSERTING IPS YOUR IP MATCH";
                      //echo "<script>alert('ERROR INSERTING IPS YOUR IP MATCH');</script>";
                  }
              }
        else
        {$msg="Your Ip AVAILABLE IN DATABASE";
            //echo "<script>alert('Your Ip AVAILABLE IN DATABASE');</script>";
        }


        $json_data = array(

                 "msg"            => $msg,



             );

 echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
die;

            ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but it shows undefined index uuser_id why

Comment: and JSON.parse show error in console.log please help me

Comment: @MusicCompany is uuser_id  equal to ip

Comment: if yes you can replace `sendcount('<?php echo $uuser_id;?>')` with `sendcount('<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>')`

Comment: $uuser_id is logged in user is so I want to insert video view only logged in users into a table so how can I do that it continue showing me errors

Comment: but i see here `unique_visitors`(`ipaddress`) VALUES ('$uuser_id')` you inserte `uuser_id as ipaddress` !!

Comment: IP address is a column in the table not $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ipaddress = $uuser_id

Comment: @MusicCompany ok great you say that $uuser_id is undefined right, how you put value in $uuser_id

Comment: @MusicCompany is $usser_id a session , post ? cuz your question dont display where is come from

Comment: $uuser is getting from table through while loop

Comment: try on that loop `var_dump($usser_id);` and see if is undefined